# No certificate templates in Certificate Services server on Windows 2019

Tags: windows, certificate-authority, windows-server-2019, ad-certificate-services

There are a lot of discussions on here about this problem, and I have spent all day exploring every one of them. All the servers involved in this are Windows 2019.  2 domain controllers and a certificate authority server.  After installing the Certificate Services feature, I then also installed the Web Enrollment stuff. But when I go to my server's enrollment site, I am greeted with this error:

[image]

I've chased down several options. I validated permissions via:
https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/windows-ssl-certificate-templates/

I verified LDAP object configurations via:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/windows-security/no-certificate-templates-be-found

I verified the configuration from this site:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/96739/certificate-template-not-showing.html

I'm running out of options. The template is clearly there:
[image]

I'm completely out of ideas. I'm frustrated by this. Has anyone got any other ideas?

Comment: Wondering why you ever need this obsolete stuff like enrollment web pages? Why not to use MMC? It is much more flexible.

Comment: While I agree with that (and add that PowerShell is also conveniently capable of issuing certs), the good old HTML3.2 web frontend *should* also still be able to show (and use) the templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my. That *can* be a tough one. After a lot of troubleshooting and cursing about mscersvc, I compiled a "top list" of my solutions. Sorry if you did some of them already.

- Check and verify https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/811418
- Ensure security permissions for the templates was set appropriately (check Application Pool Identity)
- Make sure (without any doubt!) that your AD replication is working fine and that can see your templates on *each and every* DC (!)
- Ensure that `Supply in the request` was selected under the `Subject Name` tab
- Created a brand new IIS application pool and assigned the Certsrv directory to it (triple check appropriate permissions). Bind with http only (!)
- Ensure certificate template compatibility was the same or below the domain and forest functional level (while on 2019 I wouldn't be surprised if not - most domain are on a older FL oder DL)
- Change the application pool’s identity from ApplicationPoolIdentity to NetworkService (and double check NTFS permissions. This can go strange when Certsvc was set up on a DC, which I would not recommend at all)
- Check for duplicates and/or decomissioned AD certsvcs (and issuing server name and certificate requests) with `ldifde -f check.txt -d "CN=Configuration,DC=<YOURDOM>,DC=<YOURTLD>"`. When you find a "second" one, hunt it down or remove it's templates completely. Then `repadmin /syncall /AdePq` (and wait)
- The (outdated) web console needs Read, Write, Enroll *and* Auto-enroll permissions to show the template
- Triple check your DNS. Look for SRV records for LDAP (AD) services
- Make sure your CA is using Key Storage Provider (KSP) (and SHA2) wh using 2019 as web frontend

I wish you the best of luck.

Comment: I wanted to mark yours as the answer and through my comments in below here.  Ultimately my problem was permissions. In a thread over on the Technet forums, one of the Microsoft folks suggested making sure the template had "Authenticated Users: Read. Enroll" permission set. I corrected that. But what I forgot to do was to re-publish the template. The combination of those two items solved the issue for me.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/338294/windows-certificate-services-will-not-publish-a-ce.html

Comment: Permissions, permissions, permissions ... thanks for the comment. I'll add that to the List.

Comment: I know this is necropost, but hoping for something.

I am having this same issue on a new CA I'm building in a lab to mimic my production CA.  I've got everything I can see as matching (including read/enroll for authenticated users, but I cannot view templates from the enrollment page.  I'm even a domain admin and can't view them.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into similar issue while trying to request for a new certificate from certmgr and my problem was that I did not have SRV records created in the domain for LDAP service. Packet capture on the client device showed DNS lookups failing.